# Why is schemagen not able to generate java class?

Tags: java, rdf, jena, owl, schemagen

I want to use the relation ontology in jena . I know it can be imported and tried schemagen for generating Java classes that contain the constants from ontologies and RDF schemas. But unfortunately it gives me an empty file after being created. So , does anyone tell what could be the problem or is there any alternative to it ???

Comment: "the relation ontology"  What relation ontology?

Comment: How are you trying to generate it?  What arguments/options are you passing to schemagen?  We can't help you debug a problem that we can't see.

Comment: I am invoking schemagen from command line. For that the script (with arguments specified) is :  "sh schemagen.sh -i relation.owl" this script should convert the .owl file into .java file , which it does but with no content. 
Relation ontology file I want to use is available at this link:" https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oborel/obo-relations/master/ro.owl"

Comment: you may want to look at the documentation from schemagen;  I don't think you're providing all the flags that you should.

Answer (score -1):

`Schemagen`, at least a I understand it, generates DTD files from .java or .class files. If your are trying to generate java classes, you need another tool. If you have RDF, there are a couple of tools out there: one seems to be [rdf2java](http://rdf2java.opendfki.de/), but it's hard to say how active it is. That page suggests you look at [Tripresso Wiki](http://semanticweb.org/wiki/Tripresso) for more information.

Comment: Ok i will have a look a them. Thanks !

Comment: @Nicholas the jena library comes with a schemagen tool that creates java classes with constants based on the contents of owl or rdfs files.  It's not the "usual" schemagen tool.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Ok, didn't know that. Thanks for info.